# How to get the user account duration in the Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to show how long the users are registered in a website.

Example: You created your account **5 days ago**.

How to do this?
I tried using `user_info->user_registered`, but i only got the user date...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got here.

I put comments to understand the code.

```
<?php
    $today = time(); // Get the current date 
    $user_date = strtotime(get_userdata(get_current_user_id( ))->user_registered); // Get the user registration date
    $diference = $today - $user_date; // Get the difference between today and the user registration date.
    $diferencedays = floor($diference/(60*60*24)); // Transform the date to days.
    echo $diferencedays; // Show the days.
?>
```

Is this.